# Converting date in R

Tags: r, date, converters

I want to convert those dates as this format "1995-01", "1995-02", etc.

Here is some of my data

```
              Date     Change
1     January-1995 0.01417476
2    February-1995 0.01427050
3       March-1995 0.01556348
4       April-1995 0.01644737
5         May-1995 0.01603727
6        June-1995 0.01627500
7        July-1995 0.01557800
8      August-1995 0.01429773
9   September-1995 0.01344300
10    October-1995 0.01334667
11   November-1995 0.01328429
12   December-1995 0.01345368
13    January-1996 0.01293091
14   February-1996 0.01301762
15      March-1996 0.01289048
16      April-1996 0.01268476
17        May-1996 0.01287364
18       June-1996 0.01253400
19       July-1996 0.01254591
20     August-1996 0.01271238
21  September-1996 0.01245700
22    October-1996 0.01201636
23   November-1996 0.01191300
24   December-1996 0.01195600
```

I tried this :

```
date <- as.Date(Data$Date,format="%B/%Y")
```

and this

```
date <- as.Date(paste0("01/", Data$Date),format = "%m/%Y")
```

But it juste return me

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last option can be modified to include the `%d` for day when we are `paste`ing the day.  Also, in `format`, specify the correct delimiter and `%B`- (Full month name) where as `%m`- month as decimal number)

```
as.Date(paste0("01/", Data$Date),format = "%d/%B-%Y")
```

---

Or use `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
my(Data$Date)
my("January-1995")
[1] "1995-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option, but with output of type `string` (not `Date`)

```
x <- c("January-1995", "February-1996")

paste0(
    gsub("\\D", "", x),
    "-",
    sprintf("%02d", match(gsub("-.*", "", x), month.name))
)
```

which gives

```
[1] "1995-01" "1996-02"
```